Plotting a bar graph using seaborn with hue, how to get bar labels as percentage values
I have the following data set(df):
  source_city     class         price
0    Bangalore  Business  53671.856898
1    Bangalore   Economy   6526.294410
2      Chennai  Business  54036.749819
3      Chennai   Economy   6497.568622
4        Delhi  Business  48614.172893
5        Delhi   Economy   6275.093136
6    Hyderabad  Business  50357.590531
7    Hyderabad   Economy   6207.890037
8      Kolkata  Business  56401.673678
9      Kolkata   Economy   7410.881850
10      Mumbai  Business  52666.702876
11      Mumbai   Economy   6334.098781

I want to plot a bar graph using seaborn.
I tried:
bar_plot = sns.barplot(x = 'source_city', y = 'price', hue = 'class', data = df)

# Fetching bar labels
for labels in bar_plot.containers:
     bar_plot.bar_label(labels)

But instead of the values (price), I want the percentage(price) as bar label.
How to do that, please guide.
Can I use estimator parameter, If so, how?

When mentioning "percentage", it is important to clarify what you consider 100%. Would that be one class, one city or the complete dataframe?  You can calculate the percentages via pandas, and then use these in bar_label().  Note that calling the variable for your bar groups "labels" is extremely confusing, as the second parameter to bar_label() would be the text labels.
